# Perform xmlhttprequest and afterwards direct to new url location

Tags: php, javascript, html, xml, ajax

Im new to this ajax and javascript thing. What I want is first to popup a confirm box, if true then perform xmlhttprequest. Afterwards I want to redirect the user to a new page. Here is what I've got.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUser(str)
{

var r=confirm("Delete this customer?");

    if (r==true) {

if (str=="")
{
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","sletkunde.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
}
</script>

<form onclick="showUser(id.value); return false;" >
<input type="hidden" value="<?echo $id;?>" name="id">
<input type="button" value="tryk" name="knap">
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>something here</b></div>
```

And here is the sletkunde.php

```
<?
$q=$_GET["q"];
$slet = mysql_query("DELETE FROM Kunder WHERE KundeID = '".$q."'");
echo "hey"; // Just to see if it works
?>
```

The confirm box works, the mysql_query works, the echo "hey"; works. But how can I get it to redirect to kunder.php right after all of this (automatically).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `location.href = "http://www.mysite.com/kunder.php"` in your `onreadystatechange` function.